# How to make belongs to optional for one thing and mandatory for another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

I have a `Folder` model and a `Project` model as below:

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

I am creating a folder for a project as:

```
folder = @project.folders.new(folder_params).merge(owner: current_user)
folder.save
```

I want to use the same `Folder` model for a user which has nothing to do with project like below:

```
folder = current_user.folders.new(folder_params)
folder.save
```

I have a user model as well:

```
has_many :folders, as: :owner
```

Can I make `belongs_to :project` mandatory when creating for a project and optional when creating for a user.

And what would be the best way to achieve this i.e. using same model for two purpose. I am thinking of making folder as polymorphic with folderable as well as owner as below:

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :folderable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :folders, as: :folderable
end
```

And

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :folders, as: :owner
  has_many :folders, as: :folderable
end
```

Also is it possible to declare two polymorphic in same model as I am thinking for `user` model?

Comment: Yes. Use a custom validation.

Comment: I would suggest to create `user_folders` and `project_folders` join tables and keep `folders` table connect via those join tables. In this way, you don't need to keep `FK` null.

Comment: @ArupRakshit or jvilian I have edited my requirement. Can you please suggest now?

Comment: So are you sure a Folder will never be used by both candidates?

Comment: Basically a user can create folder for self as well as for project but folder created for project has nothing to do with folder created for self.

Comment: Why don't you use just one `belongs_to :folderable, polymorphic: true` which is for both `projects` and `users`?

Comment: @chumakoff In that case how would I know that who is owner of folder created for project?

Comment: Then you need only `:owner` and `:folderable`.  `:owner` doesn't have to be polymorphic since it is a reference to a user. `:folderable` is polymorphic - it is for both `projects` and `users`

Comment: @chumakoff owner is polymorphic because there are two types of owner. One is user, other is client.

Comment: Then use two polymorphic associations: one for an owner, the other for a subject